# Evaluation of integrals involving error function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have to compute following integrals analytically:
$$I=\int_0^{A} e^{-\frac{x^2}{K}}e^{-\frac{(A-x)^2}{K}}\frac{{\rm erf}(\lambda x)}{x}dx$$
and:
$$J=\int_B^{\infty} e^{-\gamma x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{K}}\frac{{\rm erf}(\lambda x)}{x}dx$$
where $A,B,K,\lambda$ and $\gamma$ are constants such that: $(1/\lambda^2)\ll A^2\ll K$,
$B^2\ll K$
and $\lambda,\gamma = O(1)$, and $\rm erf$ is the error function.

Is there any way to evaluate those integrals ( maybe to some good approximations)?

Comment: Why do you have to compute these analytically?

Comment: Also for approximations it would be more helpful to know the scalings of $A$, $B$, and $\lambda$ with respect to $\sqrt{K}$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Those integrals arise in the intermediate steps of my calculation for a physics problem. I have edited the scaling.

Answer (score 1):

An honest attempt that didn't lead to anything useful so far.

Let's reduce the number of parameters:

$$I=\int_0^{A} e^{-\frac{x^2}{K}}e^{-\frac{(A-x)^2}{K}}\frac{{\rm erf}(\lambda x)}{x}dx$$

$$x=A y, \qquad \frac{A^2}{K} = \alpha^2 \ll 1, \qquad \lambda A = \beta \gg 1$$

$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1 e^{-2\alpha^2 (y^2+y+1/2)} \frac{{\rm erf}(\beta y)}{y}dy$$

First the note on approximations. Since $\alpha$ is small and the upper limit is $1$, we can always expand the exponential as a series. However, the resulting integrals will be complicated.

On the other hand, the error function has a nice asymptotic expansion for large arguments and a nice series for small arguments. The problem here, $\beta y$ can be both small for $y<1\beta$ and large for $y>1/\beta$, so either we need to separate the integral into two terms or use some other method.

Let's try Feynman's trick:

> $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} I(\alpha,\beta)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^1 e^{-2\alpha^2 (y^2+y+1/2)-\beta^2 y^2}dy$$

$$2\alpha^2 (y^2+y+1/2)+\beta^2 y^2=(2 \alpha^2+\beta^2) y^2+2 \alpha^2 y+\alpha^2 = \\ = (2 \alpha^2+\beta^2) \left(y^2+2 \frac{\alpha^2}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2}  y +\frac{\alpha^4}{(2 \alpha^2+\beta^2)^2}\right)-\frac{\alpha^4}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2}+\alpha^2 = \\ = (2 \alpha^2+\beta^2) \left(y+\frac{\alpha^2}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2}\right)^2+\frac{\alpha^2 (\alpha^2+\beta^2)}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2} $$

Let's rename the parameters:

$$p^2=2 \alpha^2+\beta^2 \gg 1 \\ q=\frac{\alpha^2}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2} \ll 1 \\ r^2=\frac{\alpha^2 (\alpha^2+\beta^2)}{2 \alpha^2+\beta^2} \ll 1$$

Now we have:

$$Y(p,q,r)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-r^2} \int_0^1 e^{-p^2 (y+q)^2}dy$$

> $$Y(p,q,r)=\frac{ e^{-r^2}}{ p}  \left(\operatorname{erf}(p(1+q))-\operatorname{erf}(pq) \right)$$

We also can see from the original expression that:

$$I(\alpha,0)=0$$

So we need to find the following integral:

$$I(\alpha,\beta)= \int_0^{\beta} \frac{ 1}{ \sqrt{2 \alpha^2 +t^2}} \exp \left(-\alpha^2\frac{\alpha^2+t^2}{2 \alpha^2+t^2} \right) \times \\ \times  \left(\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{3\alpha^2+t^2}{\sqrt{2 \alpha^2+t^2}} \right)-\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{\alpha^2}{\sqrt{2 \alpha^2+t^2}} \right) \right) d t$$

So I have made the integral more complicated, not less. Nice.

Note that $pq \ll 1$, but $p(1+q) \gg 1$, so again, not very nice for approximations.

However, we can simplifty a little by substitution:

$$t= \sqrt{2} \alpha u$$

$$I(\alpha,\beta)= \int_0^{\beta/(\sqrt{2} \alpha)} \frac{ 1}{ \sqrt{1 +u^2}} \exp \left(-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\frac{1+2u^2}{1+u^2} \right) \times \\ \times  \left(\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{3+2u^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \right)-\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \right) \right) d u$$

Note that this is correct numerically (gives the same values as the original integral), I checked. No mistakes so far.

Now let's make a substitution:

$$u=\sinh v, \qquad \gamma = \operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2} \alpha}, \qquad \delta =\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}} $$

$$I(\alpha,\beta)= \int_0^\gamma \exp \left(-\delta^2 \frac{\cosh 2 v}{\cosh^2  v} \right)  \left(\operatorname{erf} \left( \delta \frac{2+\cosh 2 v}{\cosh v} \right)-\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{\delta}{\cosh v} \right) \right) d v$$

This looks fun, but there's no point in trying further substitutions. I guess some other methods are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Indeed I ended up with the result you derived using the Feynman's trick just by using the integral representation of the error function. But then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @LêDũng, some approximations can surely be worked out. We can represent $$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{1/\beta} e^{-2\alpha^2 (y^2+y+1/2)} \frac{{\rm erf}(\beta y)}{y}dy+\int_{1/\beta}^1 e^{-2\alpha^2 (y^2+y+1/2)} \frac{{\rm erf}(\beta y)}{y}dy$$ and use series expansion for the first integral and asymptotic expansion of the error function for the second. I don't know how well it will work numerically though

Comment: *A more than honest attempt !*